# Xcode Objective-C Segue "Presentation in Progress"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, segue, afnetworking

I'm trying to develop an application where it allows user logins with AFNetworking. I have the database set up correctly and everything seems to be working fine except when the user first logs on.

What I have is very simplistic:

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                               onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                                   //result returned

                                   NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];

                                   if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"UserID"] intValue]>0) {
                                       [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
                                       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];
                                   } else {
                                       //error
                                       [UIAlertView title:@"Error" withMessage:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
                                   }

                               }];
```

Basically, the above code returns the result for a user login details, successful only if login details match. As you can see above, I clearly set the user in the sharedInstance, used throughout the application. After the user is set I attempt to perform the segue, as that's what a login button should do.

The segue does occur and the program is operational, but there's 2 issues I can't work out and I've been spending hours trying to fix it. First I get the message in Xcode's output window:

> Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController on LoginVC while a
>   presentation is in progress!

And secondly, to test that the user was set correct, on the Profile screen (the first screen segued to)  have a label that has it's text set to:

```
NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[[[API sharedInstance] user] objectForKey:@"username"]];
```

And it's a hit or miss whether the username actually appears or says (null) as shown:

[image]

You can also see a button I made there, to print to the output window the values of user. Even when the message is "Welcome (null)" and I press the button, all the values are correctly there so I'm unsure why the string sometimes states null.

Here's the storyboard setup regarding the issue I'm having:

[image]

If anyone could help me on this one I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you doing any configuration of your destination controller in `prepareForSegue`? Perhaps you can show us the relevant portions of `prepareForSegue` as well as `viewDidLoad` of the destination controller.

Comment: Hi Rob. My 'prepareForSegue' is:
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SignUp"])
 {
  SignUpVC *signUpVC = segue.destinationViewController;
  signUpVC.delegate = self;
 }
}`
and 'viewDidLoad' of the Profile Controller (The first controller viewed in the Tab Bar Controller) is:
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.welcomeMsg.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[[[API sharedInstance] user] objectForKey:@"username"]];
}`

Comment: Thanks. That eliminates the common source of this sort of phenomenon, where people are trying to access controls of the destination view before `viewDidLoad` is invoked. I guess the next step is to to determine was is generating the `nil` value, whether it's `[API sharedInstance]`, the `user` method of `[API sharedInstance]`, or the fact that the `NSDictionary` entry for `username` is `nil`. I'd be inclined to put debugging messages for each of those three scenarios, to determine what's the source of the `nil` value, and you can narrow down the problem from there.

Comment: Also, how is the `user` object of your `API` object defined? Certainly not `weak`, right?

Comment: Well I checked user and it's set to strong. I made this the viewDidLoad:
`CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)([API sharedInstance]));
    CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)([[API sharedInstance] user]));
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[API sharedInstance] user] objectForKey:@"username"]);
    self.welcomeMsg.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[[[API sharedInstance] user] objectForKey:@"username"]];`

Comment: And this is what was printed:
`<API, baseURL: http://localhost, defaultHeaders: {
    "Accept-Language" = "en...";
    "User-Agent" = "1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.0; Scale/1.00)";
}, registeredOperationClasses: (
), operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue>{name = 'NSOperationQueue'}>
(null)
2012-11-06 23:38:12.710 x[20513:c07] (null)
2012-11-06 23:38:13.254 x[20513:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController> on <LoginVC> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: OK, The message said "Welcome (null)" and the output window showed the message in my above comment, when I clicked the button which triggers `CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)([[API sharedInstance] user]));` the output is not null, it's correct. I don't understand how it can be null one second and not the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19193/discussion-between-rob-and-john-bale)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you correctly diagnosed, the problem is definitely some strange and/or duplicative invocation of the segues. Looking at your project, the problem is that your "Login" button has both an `IBAction` method as well as a segue from that login screen to the next controller (the tab bar controller):

[image: both IBAction and segue]

That's a problem, because the segue will be triggered when you hit the button, but will be triggered again by your `- (IBAction)login:(id)sender` code.

Because you have an `IBAction`, the segue should *not* be from the button to the next controller, but rather from the controller itself. Thus, delete your existing `Login` segue from the button to the next screen and recreate it from the controller itself:

[image: create segue from controller to next scene]

Give that new segue the "Login" identifier, and now your "Login" button will not automatically perform the segue itself, but will let the `IBAction` do its work and manually `performSegueWithIdentifier` as appropriate.

Comment: Great answer and explanation!  Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Send/trigger the event on: `Did End On Exit`

Connect it to your method invoking `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

This way it won't trigger twice.